# How can I match whole words only using INSTR in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

How can I get only the values that have a whole word match ONLY, using INSTR(needle, haystack)?

For example, I have this SQL:

```
select distinct card_name from wp_wct3 
where INSTR('mtg avacyn restored 4x Birds of Paradise x4', card_name);
```

and it returns the following results:

1| Birds of Paradise

2| Restore

However, I only want it to return 'Birds of Paradise' because it's an exact match of a word in the haystack, and not just part of one word.

How can I match whole words only using INSTR in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your words are delimited by spaces, you can use this trick:

```
where INSTR(concat(' ', 'mtg avacyn restored 4x Birds of Paradise x4', ' '),         
            concat(' ', card_name, ' '));
```

You can use the same trick with `like`:

```
where concat(' ', 'mtg avacyn restored 4x Birds of Paradise x4', ' ') like concat('% ', card_name, ' %')
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!